# xeCJK l3-too-old

Tags: xetex, errors, miktex, expl3, xecjk

I started using XeTeX and whenever I use the xeCJK package I get the following error:

```
! Critical xeCJK error: "l3-too-old" !
!
! Support package 'expl3' too old.
!
! Please update an up to date version of the bundles
! 'l3kernel' and 'l3packages'
! using your TeX package manager or from CTAN.
! Loading xeCJK will abort
!
! See the xeCJK documentation for further information.
! For immediate help type H <return>.
```

I have updated my entire repository already several times, refreshed my FNDB and so forth but the error keeps popping up and no CJK text appears in my output file.

I am using MikTex 2.9 under Windows 7 Ent 64 Bit.

here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
今日は！
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you update both in 'standard' and 'Admin' modes? MiKTeX's 'on the fly' installation can result in your packages being distributed between the two. Also, check your log file for the location of the files: this should tell you (or at least us) the likely situation.

Comment: I feel embarrassed for making such a stupid mistake! After I updated as user it works. Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: How do you switch between the two modes, and how do you update in them??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual problem here is that MiKTeX can have packages installed in both 'normal' and 'Admin' mode. The first step is therefore to try synchronising and updating both in 'normal' and 'Admin' modes.

Comment: How do you switch between the two modes, and how do you update in them??